# Input an item and gets its REGEX in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a stand alone application using Python and Tkinter.

My work is to get all similar looking product IDs from a excel sheet using Python. I got similar looking products for a particular company XYZ.

The code goes like this

```
IDs = df1['A'].str.extract(r'\b(\d{8}s\d{2})\b' , expand = False).dropna().tolist()
```

This helps extract all items which have "8 Number followed by s followed by 2 more numbers" like 01234567s12 or 98765432s23

But i want to do something opposite that is input the product ID and get its regex.
The product ID can be anything say ABC123456 or C234-D456

So is there a code which can help me get the regex ?

Comment: Strings don't "have regexes". That's something you define. Not clear what you're trying to say

Comment: is there a way in which the above is possible ?

Comment: "Similar looking" isn't something a computer understands. It's **you** that knows "some digits followed by some numbers". Therefore you provide the patterns, which you're welcome to "train a computer" to recognize, but that's all based on the knowledge of Latin characters and the decimal number system. It's possible, sure, but I don't think natural language recognition is what you're trying to do here

Comment: Then how shall we go about it ?

Comment: i want my colleagues to be able to get these simliar ids without coding. This is where the validation comes into the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `re` module to do this .

```
import re
text ="12345678S00"
y=""

for i in range(0,len(text)):
    r=re.match('[a-zA-Z]',text[i])
    if r!=None:
        y+='s'
    r=re.match('[0-9]',text[i])
    if r!=None:
        y+='\d'
    r=re.match('[.,_=&*()%^@$!#-]',text[i])
    if r!=None:
        y+='\S'

\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\ds\d\d #output
```

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is generate regex according to pattern recognition:

6numbers 2letter 2symbol 4 numbers would be :

```
\d{6}      .{2}      \S{2}       \d{4}
```

i do not know if this a good practice like this

but atleast you will have regex thats get generated.

the regex :
https://regex101.com/r/HPPAAm/1

Comment: Thank you this is helpful but still need s easier solution for my non coder colleagues

Comment: i am not sure it will get easier then this to code. all you have to do is check how many characters are in a row of the same type(letter/number/symbol) and add that as a number to one of 4 tokens and repeat this cycle.

after that, the regex is generated and you can check if there are objects with that id styling.

and if its valid you return all info back to the user.